# Добавить класс в зависимости от url

Tags: javascript, css

Стоит задача проверить урл, и если он соответствует указанному, добавить к имеющемуся классу дива еще один. Сделал так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.pathname == '/katalog-zapchastey/suzuki/'){
    $('.suzuki').addClass('suzuki1');
    }
});
</script>

<div class="suzuki"> Текст про Suzuki </div>
```

не работает

на выходе хочу

```
<div class="suzuki suzuki1"> Текст про Suzuki </div>
```

Помогите)

Comment: Условие с URL возвращает false, поэтому и не применяется класс. https://jsfiddle.net/rte9tz2z/

Answer (score 1):

В данной задаче необходимо убедиться в нескольких моментах:

1. `$(document).ready(function(){...})` - находится не в теле `<body></body>`, потому что метод `.ready()` срабатывает на окончание загрузки DOM => вся структура страницы уже загружена
2. переменная `window.location.pathname` должна строго соответствовать значению строки `"/katalog-zapchastey/suzuki/"`, как вариант для более гибкой проверки можно добавить регулярку